# Change public website for a Google Group

Tags: google-groups

I want to change the "public website" displayed in the "about" page of a Google Group, like here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!aboutgroup/editorconfig

But I can't find any interface to update this.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: The public website for a Google Group was removed.